# Multiple implicit conversion operators

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, clang++, conditional-operator, conversion-operator

Consider the following C++ code:

```
struct X {
    operator int();
    operator char();
};

struct Y {
    operator int();
    operator char();
};

void f(bool z) { 
    z ? X() : Y(); 
}
```

GCC compiles it successfully. Clang gives an error:

> error: conditional expression is ambiguous; 'X' and 'Y' can be
>   converted to several common types

MSVC also gives an error:

> error C2446: ':': no conversion from 'Y' to 'X'
>
> note: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Which compiler is correct here, and what is the relevant part of the C++ Standard in this case? My guess is [over.match.oper] is applicable, but so far I was not able to figure out the expected behavior from it.

*Update:* if we change both `operator int()` to convert to some other type, e.g. `operator bool()`, then GCC gives an error as well. Maybe there is some special rule about `int` type?

Comment: I believe gcc's behaviour is correct. In the `bool` case it is ambiguous because `bool` to `int` and `char` to `int` are equal

Answer (score 2):

I think it's stated here, [[expr.cond]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cond#6):

(emphasis mine)

> Otherwise, the result is a prvalue. If the second and third operands do not have the same type, and either has (possibly cv-qualified) class type, **overload resolution is used to determine the conversions (if any) to be applied to the operands ([over.match.oper], [over.built]). If the overload resolution fails, the program is ill-formed**. Otherwise, the conversions thus determined are applied, and the converted operands are used in place of the original operands for the remainder of this subclause.

That means, given `X` and `Y`, which are two different types, overload solution will try to determine any conversion which could be applied. Overload solution fails because both `X` and `Y` could be converted to multiple types. The program is ill-formed; Clang is correct.

Note that overload resolution fails because there're multiple conversions for `X` and `Y` then the conversion can't be determined. That means even they might have common type after appropriate conversion is performed, the following code is still ill-formed.

```
struct X {
    operator int();
};

struct Y {
    operator int();
    operator char();
};

void f(bool z) { 
    z ? X() : Y(); 
}
```

Error message from [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/srehsXwMrD5Rh1mv):

> ```
> prog.cc:11:7: error: conditional expression is ambiguous; 'X' and 'Y' can be converted to several common types
>     z ? X() : Y(); 
>       ^ ~~~   ~~~
> ```